# match any character followed by exclamation mark and replace it with a whitespace and a exclamation mark

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I have the following sentences:

```
hello!
hello?
goodbye!!!
goodbye???
```

I want a regex to modify them like this:

```
hello !
hello ?
goodbye !!!
goodbye ???
```

I tried with:

```
re.sub(r"(\w)\1([!?])\2", r'\1 \2', sentence)
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: You need to escape the question mark  `([!\?])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern `(\w)\1([!?])\2` does not work because it uses 2 capture groups with a 2 backreferences, meaning that the value of the backreference should be the same as the capture group.

Also like this the pattern needs at least 4 characters.

You could write the pattern like this:

```
(\w)([!?])
```

See a [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZwUaj/1).

In the replacement use:

```
\1 \2
```

Example

```
re.sub(r"(\w)([!?])", r'\1 \2', sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\b([?!])
```

`\b` word boundary.

`([?!])` a literal `?` or `!`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UhmO00/1)

```py
re.sub(r"\b([?!])", r' \1', sentence)
```